# Position and momentum eigenstates in terms of creation and annihilation operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a simple harmonic oscillator; the position operator is $\hat{x}=(a^\dagger+a)/\sqrt{2}$ and the momentum operator is $\hat{p}=-i(a-a^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$.

One may verify that the eigenstates of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ are $$\left|x\right>\propto e^{\sqrt{2}~xa^\dagger-(a^\dagger)^2/2}\left|0\right>$$
$$\left|p\right>\propto e^{ip\sqrt{2} ~a^\dagger+(a^\dagger)^2/2}\left|0\right>.$$
My question is: how do I verify that the position eigenstates and momentum eigenstates are orthogonal themselves, and that $$\left<x|p\right>\propto e^{ipx} ~~?$$
I'm not able to calculate this inner product using the commutator of $a$ and $a^\dagger$.

Comment: @knzhou what do you mean by that? Yes I want a direct approach.

Comment: is this correct?  what is $z$ in your first exponential?  Moreover, is $p$ in your second exponential an operator or a number?

Comment: [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) and friends are what you want to commute exponentials of operators. What's the conceptual question here? What have you tried?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Hi, of course I know I can use BCH formula to do that calculation. The problem is that when you use BCH formula, you need to calculate infinite number of commutators, and because the $a^2$ and $(a^\dagger)^2$, they don't vanish after a few order.

Comment: Without an i your normalization of your *p* is toxically antihermitean, and prevents your from simple implementation of adjoint symmetries involved. Your combinatorics would be *vastly* expedited by utilizing the isomorphism  $a^\dagger \to y$ and $a \to \partial_y$, after you normalize your a's properly, provided you understand translation operators.

Comment: Formally related question [292899](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292899/creating-a-state-of-definite-position-in-qm/293059#293059) .

Comment: @CosmasZachos Hi, this is part of the problem 14.4 in Schwartz's QFT book.  My final goal is to understand the orthonormality of the eigenstates of a quantum field, see this problem http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312006/. But to solve that problem, I think I first need to understand how to show that $\left<x|p\right>=e^{ipx}$. About the quantum field eigenstate problem, I couldn't find any books or papers talking about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, the QFT theory problem is a straightforward extension of this one. But unless reopened, I can't help you here. You have to tweak the *standard*  techniques of [Fisher, Nieto, & Sandberg](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1107).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the paper, it seems pretty relevant! I'm not able to reopen this problem.