# Does the Expected Value of Creation Operator Depend on Time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I am asking a conceptual portion of a previously asked question now that I have a better understanding of what is going on. Also asked on MathSE, but it may better fit in here.. (for context, see: [1-D Simple Harmonic Oscillator with Dirac Notation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294082/1-d-simple-harmonic-oscillator-with-dirac-notation?noredirect=1#comment660724_294082))

I have a state vector for a 1-D quantum oscillator at $t = 0$: $$|\Psi(t=0)\rangle = A \sum_{q=0}^{Q_o} \frac{1}{q+i}|\phi_q\rangle$$

where $Q_o$ is an arbitrary, positive, finite integer, $A$ is a normalization constant, and $q$ represents the quantum number of the system. I would like to determine the expectation value of the creation operator $\hat{a}^\dagger$ for the state vector at times *greater* than $t=0$. That is, I want to determine: $$\langle\Psi(t)|\hat{a}^\dagger|\Psi(t)\rangle$$

From my understanding, I should be able to tack on a time dependent function ($e^\frac{-iE_q t}{\hbar}$) to the prefactor of $|\phi_q\rangle$, which should give me the result that $$|\Psi(t)\rangle = A\sum_{q=0}^{Q_o} \frac{e^{-iE_qt/\hbar}}{q+i}|\phi_q\rangle$$

Now, if I attempt to take the conjugate transpose of $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ to obtain $\langle\Psi(t)|$, would the time dependence not cancel out due to the complex conjugate of the time dependent function? That is, I will end up with

$$\langle\Psi(t)| = A^*\sum_{p=0}^{Q_o} \frac{e^{iE_pt/\hbar}}{p-i}\langle\phi_p|$$

Then putting it all together, $$\langle\Psi(t)|\hat{a}^\dagger|\Psi(t)\rangle = |A|^2\sum_{p}\sum_{q}\frac{e^{iE_pt/\hbar}}{p-i}\frac{e^{-iE_qt/\hbar}}{q+i}\langle\phi_p|\hat{a}^\dagger |\phi_q\rangle$$

$$=|A|^2\sum_{p}\sum_{q}\frac{1}{(p-i)(q+i)}\langle\phi_p|\hat{a}^\dagger |\phi_q\rangle$$

$\hat{a}^\dagger |\phi_q\rangle$ leads to $\sqrt{q+1}|\phi_{q+1}\rangle$, where if $\langle \phi_p|$ is then applied to this results in $\sqrt{q+1}\delta_{p,q+1}$

Finally, collapsing the sum according to the Kronecker delta function, I obtain the expectation value as $$\langle \hat{a}^\dagger \rangle = |A|^2\sum_{q}\frac{\sqrt{q+1}}{((q+1)-i)(q+1)}$$

which holds no time dependence. This doesn't make sense to me when I consider how the creation and annihilation operators are obtained from the position and momentum operators $\hat{x}, \hat{p}$ which are time dependent.

So my main question here (sorry for the long read) is: does it make sense for the expectation value of a creation operator to not hold time dependence when corresponding with a time *dependent* state vector? And if it *should* be time dependent, what am I doing wrong mathematically?

Comment: Unless $E_p = E_q$ the phase factors don't cancel.

Comment: OH! and according to the Kronecker delta, $E_p = E_{q+1}$ not $E_q$? So when I collapse the sum will I end up with a time dependent factor now of $e^{\frac{-it}{\hbar}(E_q - E_{q+1})}$?